Nutanix user restricted access
i am running Nutanix AHV cluster, and i would like to create a user that has restricted access to particular VMs inside the cluster. Lets say i want the user to be able to view and restart (basic access) only 3 VMs in the cluster of 20
I am aware about user, cluster and backup admin roles in prism element but those are not sufficient for my task.
I have played with creation of custom role in IAM on prism central, but also the entity "VM" seems to be for all the VMs since i have no option to choose
Version pc.2023.4
NCC Version: 4.6.6
LCM Version: 2.7.1
Thanks in advance
